# Updating a Pie Chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have searched all throughout StackOverflow at the many examples of updating pie charts and looked through the d3.js blocks related to updating pie charts in d3.js, but I can't seem to do just a simple update using d3.js version 4. I'm sure I'm missing something crucial, but I don't see it. The idea is that clicking the "Update" button will just change the data to a different set, which is only different by one element. I have a Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/qL9yy2b2/1/) that shows the code I have at this point in action (or inaction, as the case may be).

The initial call to the update function creates the pie chart based on the first dataset, but the second call, initiated by the "Update" button, does nothing. I know that the pie generator is generating the correct object (I inspected the object to check), but no paths are redrawn.

The following is the code:

```
var pieGenerator = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.quantity;})
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

var fruits = [
  {name: 'Apples', quantity: 20},
  {name: 'Bananas', quantity: 40},
  {name: 'Cherries', quantity: 50},
  {name: 'Damsons', quantity: 10},
  {name: 'Elderberries', quantity: 30},
];
var fruits2 = [
  {name: 'Blueberries', quantity: 40},
  {name: 'Bananas', quantity: 40},
  {name: 'Cherries', quantity: 50},
  {name: 'Damsons', quantity: 10},
  {name: 'Elderberries', quantity: 30},
];

var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(75)
  .outerRadius(200)
  .padAngle(.02)
  .padRadius(100)
  .cornerRadius(4);

function doUpdate() {
  update(fruits2);
}

function update(myData) {

  var arcData = pieGenerator(myData);
  var colorDomain = myData.map(function(a) {return a.name;});
  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(colorDomain)
    .range(['#ff2800','#58595B','#006c93','#8D2048','#00746F'])

  // Create a path element and set its d attribute
  var u = d3.select('g')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(arcData);

  u.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arcGenerator)
    .each(function(d){
      d3.select(this)
        .style('fill',function(d) {
          return colorScale(d.data.name);
        })
    });

  u.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have only an "enter" and an "exit" selection inside your update function.

You have to create an "update" selection, like this:

```
var u = d3.select('g')
    .selectAll('path');

u.data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .merge(u)
    .attr('d', arcGenerator)
    .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .style('fill', function(d) {
                return colorScale(d.data.name);
            })
    });

u.exit().remove();
```

Here is your updated (no pun intended) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbjt80ts/

And the same code in the Stack snippet:

```js
var pieGenerator = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.quantity;
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

var fruits = [{
  name: 'Apples',
  quantity: 20
}, {
  name: 'Bananas',
  quantity: 40
}, {
  name: 'Cherries',
  quantity: 50
}, {
  name: 'Damsons',
  quantity: 10
}, {
  name: 'Elderberries',
  quantity: 30
}, ];
var fruits2 = [{
  name: 'Blueberries',
  quantity: 40
}, {
  name: 'Bananas',
  quantity: 40
}, {
  name: 'Cherries',
  quantity: 50
}, {
  name: 'Damsons',
  quantity: 10
}, {
  name: 'Elderberries',
  quantity: 30
}, ];

function doUpdate() {
  update(fruits2);
}

// Create an arc generator with configuration
var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(75)
  .outerRadius(200)
  .padAngle(.02)
  .padRadius(100)
  .cornerRadius(4);

function update(myData) {

  var arcData = pieGenerator(myData);
  var colorDomain = myData.map(function(a) {
    return a.name;
  });
  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(colorDomain)
    .range(['#ff2800', '#58595B', '#006c93', '#8D2048', '#00746F'])

  // Create a path element and set its d attribute
  var u = d3.select('g')
    .selectAll('path');

  u.data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .merge(u)
    .attr('d', arcGenerator)
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style('fill', function(d) {
          return colorScale(d.data.name);
        })
    });

  u.exit().remove();
}
update(fruits);
```

```css
path {
  fill: orange;
  stroke: white;
}

text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: white;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <button onClick="doUpdate();">Update</button>
</div>
<svg width="700" height="500">
  <g transform="translate(300, 250)"></g>
</svg>
```